# Blocking messages with an empty message-id in postfix

Tags: postfix

I've been receiving some spam where the message-id is empty, for example:

Sep 18 12:07:16 postfix/cleanup[21530]: message-id=<>

I don't use SpamAssassin. Is there a way using postfix to refuse any messages with an empty message-id?

Would this be a bad idea? I've looked through my maillog and only spam messages are showing empty message-ids, but of course I'd like to minimize refusing legitimate messages.

*** Update
Thinking of trying something like this in main.cf:

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre
```

with header_checks.pcre like this:

```
/message-id:[\s]*<>/i REJECT Invalid message format.
```

or

```
/message-id:[ ]*<>/i REJECT Invalid message format.
```

Thanks bqb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pcre syntax should do the job

```
/^Message-ID:[[:space:]]*(<>)?[[:space:]]*$/ REJECT Invalid message format
```

Some caveats:

- In case message-ID header line is missing, [postfix insert that header](http://www.postfix.org/cleanup.8.html) and [ignore your header_checks rule](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html).
- Rejecting message based on message-id is not recommended. Some MTA/web apps may behave differently and caused legitimate email rejected. Some organizations may prefer "ten false negative is better than one false positive" and other organizations may prefer otherwise.
- Before applying to production mode, please test it by add WARN instead of REJECT

  ```
  /^Message-ID:[[:space:]]*(<>)?[[:space:]]*$/ WARN Invalid message format
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this. As you mentioned, the Message-ID wasn't empty but was simply not present - so the header check failed anyway during a brief test.  Also I have found a few legitimate messages in the log that have no message-IDs, and so have decided not to block them.   In the end I simply used my IP filter software to block the repeat offenders.  Thanks